# Delete docker images with same name

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

Server storing multiple docker images with same name but with different tags, I am finding the good command which will search docker images with same name, but with different tags, and delete all, saving only the newest.
Example.

```
TestImage:v1
TestImage:v2
TestImage:v3
TestImage:v4
```

The command will delete all images which have name "TestImage" but save TestImage:v4 (which is newest by date).

The actual command .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have the docker cli installed, the following should work:

```sh
image_ids=$(docker image ls "$name" -q | tail -n +2 | xargs)
docker image rm "$image_ids"
```

The first command loads all local images with the given name. Using the `-q` flag means that only the image ids are being outputted.
the `tail` program then skips the first one of these ids (in other words, starts reading at line 2). Since images are sorted from new to old, this means the newest image is skipped.
The `xargs` then brings all the outputted ids into the same line, so that `docker` can interpret them easily.

The ids obtained in that step may look something like this:

```
ae3c4906b72c 650d66a00131 18cac929dc4f
```

`docker image rm` will then remove all images with these ids.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working great, can we customize script to not specify 'image name', but allow script to find every image with this rule?

Comment: @devops212123 I'm not completely sure if this is what you mean, but, rather then image, you can also specify globs. For instance, if you are looking for python images, with a slim tag, you could write `python:*-slim` where I previously wrote `"$name"`